# Can ffmpeg create DVD subtitle streams from (Advanced) SubStation Alpha files?

Tags: subtitles, dvd

As the title says, I'm wondering if ffmpeg can create DVD subtitle streams from .ass or .ssa files. The key point being that I want libass to be used when rendering the subpictures, so they get rendered exactly according to the file.

I've tried something like `ffmpeg -i input.avi -i input.ass -f vob -c:v mpeg2video -c:a ac3 -c:s dvdsub out.vob` but it fails saying that picture subtitles are needed.

I've also tried using spumux from the dvdauthor package, and while it does render subpictures, it reads only the timestamps and the text from the input, thus making the use of .ass or .ssa pointless.

If ffmpeg can't do it, what other options are there? CLI applications running on FreeBSD are prefered (most Linux open source applications can be compiled on FreeBSD, so those are fine), but I'll consider Windows GUI applications as well.

Comment: Appears not. Try https://sourceforge.net/projects/maestrosbt/

Comment: @Mulvya That may work, and I'll look into it if I don't find anything else. I would prefer CLI aplications able to run on FreeBSD. I just edited my question to include that.